How do I login to my Microsoft account to automate tests on Dynamics 365 and Azure Web Apps with Playwright?
I'm looking to automate testing with Playwright on Dynamics 365 and Azure Web Apps.
To test on those services, I need to login to my Microsoft account.
However, my company has a conditional access policy to login to Microsoft. When I try to automate the login process with Playwright, I run into error code 53003, stating
"You cannot access this right now
Your sign-in was successful, but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser, app or location that is restricted by your admin."
If I cannot login to my Microsoft account, I cannot run any tests.
I have tried:

Scripting the actual login process into the test;
Creating a GlobalSetup.ts file to login and save the StorageState before running normal tests; and
Creating dependencies to login and save the StorageState before running normal tests.

All failed to 53003.
Other than changing company policy on conditional access, is there any way I can point Playwright to run tests in my everyday browsers (e.g. Edge and Google Chrome) which are already authenticated and trusted?
Thanks!

Please share your code so far so there's something concrete to discuss and debug here. Thanks.
